# Disable item on the CompletionList of the Autocompleteextender

Tags: autocompleteextender

Is there a way to disable a item on the completion list of the AutoCompleteExtender? I want to disable the selection on the list if a particular row has some text in it like, 'Match Not Found'.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that allows you clear the items of the CompletionList, so if you select the empty item on the list, it clears the TargetControl that your AutoCompleteExtender is set to.

Please see:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1739879.aspx?disable+Autocomplete+Extender+on+client